# getElementsByClassName - Undefined Return

Tags: google-tag-manager, getelementsbyclassname

I am having issues with a getElementsByClassName function I am using in Google Tag Manager.
I will need to capture an input field value in my client's form and I am isolating the class name and using it in my custom JS however I am only getting Undefined back.
The JS I am using is the below and I've also created a gtm.formsubmit event but I reckon that the event is firing before it has time to listen to the user input, it that even possible?

`function() {
  var inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-form");
  return inputField.value || "";
}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is just a single element with the class wpcf7-form a call to `getElementsByClassName` will return an array of elements (in that case a single element). Since an array has no "value" attribute you get an "undefined".

If you are resonably sure there is only one element with the class you can do

```
...      
var inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-form");
return inputField[0].value || "";
...
```

since a single element will always be at index 0. In that case it would be easier to use a DOM type variable in Google Tag Manager and set the selection method to "CSS selector". This will return the first element with your class (or undefined if not present).